# Why does my DSLR stop recording video even with a fast (class 10) SDHC card?

Tags: troubleshooting, video, sdcard, sdhc, hd-video

I am recording video with my Canon T2i DSLR, but it keeps stopping to say video recording has stopped automatically. I googled the problem and read that my SD card has to be fast for it to work. While I am recording 1080p at 30 FPS, I have a Transcend class 10 16GB SDHC card which makes it seem unlikely that the card is the source of the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: There are a lot of counterfeit cards floating around. If you got it on eBay it is probably fake. Try another card purchased through a reputable dealer.

Comment: I purchased it directly from Amazon. Any other suggestions?

Comment: How long before it stops? There are limits to prevent it being classed as a video camera.

Comment: A few seconds. It's a Canon EOS Rebel T2i.

Comment: Get a quality card that has reliable write-speed. Despite high-ratings, low-end cards often cannot sustain their advertised speed continuously.

Comment: [Here's another SE user](http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9918/why-does-my-class-10-memory-card-run-in-to-buffering-problems) with a Transcend Class 10 not working for 1080p@30fps.

Comment: As much as I like (and use daily) Transcend's external hard drives and USB sticks (those things are indestructible), as far as SD cards go, Sandisk for example, does them much more consistent with the declaration on the label. Theirs are more expensive, but those few dollars are really pittance compared to the feeling when the card is not working properly or (may it not happen) dies on you.

Comment: @mathguy54 Amazon has been known to get a batch of bad SD cards before (from any of the major makers). They will usually swap them for cards from a different batch if it is known issue. Have you checked the reviews that were written for your exact card at around the same time you bought yours?

Comment: Further to @MichaelClark's point, you may be entitled to a refund if the product doesn't perform as specified (depending on local consumer laws and/or store policy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benchmark the card read/write speeds on your (or someone else's) computer.

Class 10 [should](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Speed_class_rating) read & write at speeds of *at least* 10 MB/sec.

For stable recording at 1080p@30fps, you probably need about 6 MB/sec minimum write speed. If the card isn't performing at its specified rate, then this could be your problem.

You could use something like [hdtune](http://www.hdtune.com/) on Windows, or [Blackmagic Disk Speed Test](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/blackmagic-disk-speed-test/id425264550?mt=12) on Mac OS X.

Comment: I think that was the issue. PSA: buy reputable SD cards!

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind:

1. Check your owner manual to verify your card is compatible with
   your camera.
2. then, go to the card maker website and search cards
   for highest transfer speed for your camera.

This should help you to rate your card.

You'll find higher transfer speeds cost more money.
Example: 95mb transfer speed for my camera was $60.

Comment: HD video requires about 6MB/sec. *write speed*. Transfer speed is usually measured as *read speed*. In either case a 95MB read speed is overkill if the only concern is recording HD video. The problem here isn't a card that *only* writes at 10MB/sec. The problem is likely a card that is *supposed* to write at 10MB/sec but doesn't.